# Mongoose Map of object array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm learning mongodb and mongoose, and i can't figure out how to work with this schema :

```
mongoose.Schema({
  laps: {
    type: Map,
    of: [{type: ObjectId, ref:'Lap'}]
  }
}, {collection: 'xxx'});
```

I've try to push the array like that :

```
this.laps.set(key, (this.laps.get(key)).push(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(newLap._id)));

Map { '5bd1b3bfbef1001d64de6697' => ["5c0a3c0456be700670ed093b"] }
```

Each time i try to save the model i get this error:

```
validation failed: laps.5bd1b3bfbef1001d64de6697: Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "[1]" at path "laps.$*"
```

And i'm stuck there

Comment: In the laps schema make sure, ObjectId belongs to `Schema.Types.ObjectId`.

Comment: It belongs to ObjectId  (ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;), it work perfectly on all my other schema

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Old stuff so putting here in case other people find it while looking at some similar problem, but Array.push returns the length of the new array, not the array itself, so that's why instead of an expected array of objectId you give [1] to map.set, and the error message is explicit. Here you can do it in several steps, first creating new_array = this.lap.get(key), then new_array.push(...) then calling set(key, new_array)